# Is it a good idea to add errors to the model object?

Tags: ios, swift

Consider a network request that fetches sections of results to be displayed using the structs below in a `UICollectionView` or `UITableView`. Here we are interested in showing partial results i.e If a certain section has an error associated with it we show an error message to the user in that section and show the rest of the sections that have items normally. Also, if there is an error the corresponding section would have zero items.

Should the errors associated with the sections be returned in a map (or an array) separate from the model object (`SearchResult`) or is it better to provide an error property in the model objects i.e `SearchSection` itself?

1st Method:

```
enum SectionTitle: String {
  case first
  case second
  case third
}

struct SearchResult {
   var sections: [SearchSection]
}

struct SearchSection {
   var title: SectionTitle
   var items: [Item]
}

typealias SearchErrorsMap = [SectionTitle:Error]
func fetchItems(for query: SearchQuery, completion: @escaping (SearchResult,SearchErrorsMap) -> ()) {...}
```

2nd method

```
enum SectionTitle: String {
   case first
   case second
   case third
}

struct SearchResult {
    var sections: [SearchSection]
}

struct SearchSection {
    var title: SectionTitle
    var items: [Item]
    var error: Error?
}

func fetchItems(for query: SearchQuery, completion: @escaping (SearchResult) -> ()) {...}
```

Comment: does single `fetchItems` request retrieve multiple sections? Or each `fetchItems` retrieves 1 section?

Comment: fetchItem returns a `SearchResult` in the completion handler which has an array of `SearchSection`, so yes assume that it retrieves all the sections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your model is trying to capture whether a search result was successful or not, it’s fine for it to contain the respective error, if any.

So, let’s consider the proposed model:

```
struct SearchSection {
    var title: SectionTitle
    var items: [Item]
    var error: Error?
}
```

The problem here is that it’s not entirely clear the relationship between `items` and `error`. Presumably if there’s an error, then `items` would be empty. But I might suggest a model that makes this relationship explicit:

```
struct SearchSection {
    let title: SectionTitle
    let result: Result<[Item], Error>
}
```

If `result` is `.success`, the associated value will be an array of values, `[Item]`. If `result` is `.failure`, then the associated value will be the error. It makes it explicit that it is one or the other.